# Getting Serverless Error spawn python3.8 ENOENT in sls deploy for python requirements

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, serverless

Doing a serverless deployment using sls deploy and getting error "spawn python3.8 ENOENT"

```
ubuntu@jumpboxAndawscli:$ sudo sls deploy --stage prod
Serverless: Configuration warning at ‘provider’: unrecognized property ‘configfile’
Serverless:
Serverless: Learn more about configuration validation here:
Serverless:
Serverless: Updated deployment bucket public access block
Serverless: [serverless-package-external] is complete
Serverless: Generated requirements from /data/integrations/requirements.txt in /data/integrations/.serverless/requirements.txt…
Serverless: Installing requirements from /home/ubuntu/.cache/serverless-python-requirements/c83840509c18324c044b580033bb40d7104080235af12a1d9e3d118cf0675070_x86_64_slspyc/requirements.txt …
Serverless: Using download cache directory /home/ubuntu/.cache/serverless-python-requirements/downloadCacheslspyc

Error ---------------------------------------------------

Error: spawn python3.8 ENOENT
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:19)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:470:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)

 For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.
Your Environment Information ---------------------------
Operating System: linux
Node Version: 12.22.1
Framework Version: 2.72.2
Plugin Version: 5.5.4
SDK Version: 4.3.1
Components Version: 3.18.2
```

Answer (score 6):

Your local available python (current PATH) version MUST be the same version configured in your serverless.yml provider runtime value.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, but with python 3.9.

In my serverless.yaml file I had the `runtime: python3.9` configured.
In my machine, when I ran `python3 --version` the result was `3.9.5`.

After some time trying to understand, I finally saw that if I tried to run `python3.9 --version` in my machine, **it didn't work**.

Trying to connect the dots, I imagined that the serverless framework program needed the exact `python3.9` bin name.

To solve the problem I downloaded the binaries from the [Python Website](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/), installed it and ran `serverless deploy` again. **It worked!!!**

To help you with the installation, in case you need (Ubuntu):

```
$ cd /opt
$ sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.13/Python-3.9.13.tgz
$ sudo tar xzf Python-3.9.13.tgz
$ cd Python-3.9.13
$ sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
$ sudo make altinstall
```

There are probably other solutions for this problem like using venv or symlinks, but this one helped me first. I hope it helps you too.

Answer (score 0):

For me, when I changed the python version from 3.8 to 3.6 in serverless.yml then only it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar message on Mac; I ran `brew install python@3.8`, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In the file

```
serverless.yaml,
```

setup

```
runtime: python3.11
```

#Example

/mydir_py3_11/django_aws_lambda_002/django-aws-lambda/serverless.yaml

```
service: django-aws-lambda

plugins:
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin
  - serverless-prune-plugin
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-wsgi
useDotenv: true
variablesResolutionMode: 20210326

custom:
  dotenv:
    logging: false
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
    zip: true
    fileName: requirements.txt
  stage: ${env:STAGE, 'default'}
  wsgi:
    app: django_aws_lambda.wsgi.application
    packRequirements: false
  prune:
    automatic: true
    number: 3

functions:
  - app:
      handler: wsgi_handler.handler
      events:
        - http: ANY /
        - http: ANY /{proxy+}
      timeout: 30

provider:
  name: aws
  role: arn:aws:iam::198784529794:role/exec_lambda
  profile: admin
  region: us-east-1
  runtime: python3.11
  versionFunctions: false
  stage: ${env:STAGE, 'default'}
  timeout: 60
  vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
      - sg-e2a9ddd5
      - sg-01d23aa5252981a2b
    subnetIds:
      - subnet-5751da76
      - subnet-36aa2369
      - subnet-65ea6603
      - subnet-3927f708
      - subnet-31623e7c
      - subnet-ff4f09f1
  deploymentBucket:
    name: ${env:DEPLOYMENT_BUCKET}
  apiGateway:
    shouldStartNameWithService: true
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221

package:
  individually:
    true
  exclude:
    - .cache/**
    - .env
    - .git/**
    - .github/**
    - .pytest_cache/**
    - .serverless/**
    - node_modules/**
    - static/**
    - db.sqlite3
```